# XNA SoundEffect Distortion

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

So I am currently making a game where you are running and defeating enemies. When you get to the boss and kill him he has a death sound, but what happens is that is plays the death sound all distorted. I don't know what is going on, sometimes are better than others but they are all distorted. MonsterA is my boss Monster and enemy health is his health. here is my code(This is in the Draw() Method):

```
 if (enemyHealth == 0)
        {

            sprite.PlayAnimation(deathAnimation);
            if (spriteSet != "MonsterA")
            {
                killedSound.Play();
            }

            if (spriteSet == "MonsterA")
            {

              bossKilledSound.Play();
            }

                isDead = true;
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to play that sound on every tick of the game loop, perhaps? I assume killedSound is a SoundEffectInstance, yes?

Comment: try `if (enemyHealth == 0 && isDead == false`)

Comment: Or simpler: (if enemyHealth == 0 && !isDead) Or <= 0 to be certain you've caught a negative health situation, if that's possible for your scenario :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in the `Update` method. The `Draw` method is ment (pretty much) only for drawing. Also, it's not very clear to me, but the `Draw` function does't fire just every time after `Update`. I think it's **kind of** async, but watis for `Update`. It's a foggy topic for me, but try putting that code in `Update` instead of `Draw`. If that's not the case, try running the game on another PC that is much slower or much faster than the one you are debugging on. That should lead you to the next clue why is this happening.
**EDIT:**
... assuming that you are not starting the sound on every fire of Draw/Update, witch is not likely because from your explanation, other sounds play well, and only this one is the problem.